# Jest mock global navigator.onLine

Tags: mocking, jestjs, global

How do you mock `global.navigator.onLine` in jest for React.

My version of jest is the latest `24.9.0`

I've tried

```js
global.navigator = {
  onLine: false,
}
```

and using `jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({onLine: false}))`

They still seem to return `true` for `navigator.onLine`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [jest.spyOn(object, methodName, accessType?)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname-accesstype) method to mock the value of the read-only property `onLine` for `navigator`.
Besides, it's nothing related about UI library `reactjs`.

> Since Jest 22.1.0+, the jest.spyOn method takes an optional third argument of accessType that can be either 'get' or 'set', which proves to be useful when you want to spy on a getter or a setter, respectively.

For example:

`index.ts`:

```js
export function main() {
  if (navigator.onLine) {
    console.log('online');
  } else {
    console.log('offline');
  }
}
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import { main } from './';

describe('main', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  test('should log "online"', () => {
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    jest.spyOn(navigator, 'onLine', 'get').mockReturnValueOnce(true);
    main();
    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith('online');
  });

  test('should log "offline"', () => {
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    jest.spyOn(navigator, 'onLine', 'get').mockReturnValueOnce(false);
    main();
    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith('offline');
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/58603653/index.spec.ts (10.016s)
  main
    ✓ should log "online" (14ms)
    ✓ should log "offline" (7ms)

  console.log node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:860
    online

  console.log node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:860
    offline

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.259s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/58603653

Comment: I followed your approach, but when I create the test I got an error: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null Jest`. In my case, I have 4 lines of code that manipulates the DOM (printing messages in the HTML)

Comment: I've copied your code, and `jest.spyOn()` isn't changing the value of `navigator.onLine`. Not sure what the problem is.