# using AudioContext with jest

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

I have some components that inject services using `AudioContext` like

```
`my service constructor`

constructor() {
  this.context = new AudioContext();
}
```

but jest keeps telling me `AudioContext is not defined`

I've looked at the other answers but most of the time the `AudioContext` is passed as an argument in my case this is instantiated inside a dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [issuecomment-599795854](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2900#issuecomment-599795854)

> JSDOM doesn’t currently support the WebAudio specification.

A solution is to create the mock `AudioContext` and put it in setupFile.

e.g.

`index.ts`:

```
export function main() {
  const context = new AudioContext();
  context.createOscillator();
  context.createGain();
  return context;
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
import { main } from '.';

describe('78023642', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    const context = main();
    expect(context).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

`jest.setup.js`:

```js
class AudioContextMock {
  createOscillator() {}
  createGain() {}
}

global.AudioContext = AudioContextMock;
```

`jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
};
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/78023642/index.test.ts
  78023642
    √ should pass (1 ms)                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.753 s, estimated 1 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

package versions:

```json
"jest": "^29.7.0",
"jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
```

Comment: thanks it worked but for some reason I've tried implementing the same mocking logic (without class) for the `navigator` object and it doesn't look like it's working any quick idea?Thanks in advance

Comment: @JSmith Please search on the internet, see https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/717#issuecomment-187017936, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58603653/jest-mock-global-navigator-online etc... If those don't solve your issue, ask a new question. Take a look [Mocking methods which are not implemented in JSDOM](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-methods-which-are-not-implemented-in-jsdom)